# How can I stretch the image in imagebutton to the whole area of the imagebutton?

Tags: android, image, imagebutton, stretch

Here is a picture that will help you understand my problem:

[image: It's a "1"]

I want to stretch the image shown inside `ImageButton` to the whole area of the `ImageButton`.
As you can see, the picture with the number 1 only take about 95% of the `ImageButton` and you can also see the boundaries of the `ImageButton`.

**I still want to maintain the image button style**

Here's how I am using ImageView:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/secondActivityBbuttonDownRight"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/111" />
```

**I think I found out what is my problem.
I need a custom component that can contain only an image and have a clicking effect.**

Comment: use this android:background="@drawable/111"

Comment: add android:background="@android:color/transparent" to the ImageButton

Comment: I edited you post, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85516/ for how to add an image to your post.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation points in order to do so

Comment: I simply added this within the ImageButton xml - android:background="@null"

Comment: Replace this with android:src="@drawable/111" to android:background="@drawable/111"

Answer (score 66):

ImageButton is ImageView.
If you want your image to fill button
than set `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, so the image you set in `android:src` will be stretched to fill whole image button.

ImageButton has a background under your image and padding.
If you do not want background
set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.
If you do not want padding
set `android:padding="0"` or set background without padding.

Comment: Good answer thanks, but you need units on the padding: android:padding="0dip"

Comment: I think padding no longer is part of the ImageButton

Answer (score 7):

`android:scaleType="fitXY"` tested and works correctly.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:padding="0dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code :-

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/secondActivityBbuttonDownRight"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:background="@drawable/111" />
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem.
I want to use the style of the image button & stretch the image

Comment: scaletype used with background (doesn't apply on background ...)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a 9-patch image to make the image fit correctly on an `ImageButton` in case you need to stretch it, but you don't want the image to become distorted.

To have a button with an image that completely covers it, you can use something like this:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/iconBtn"
  android:layout_width="64dip"
  android:layout_height="64dip"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_button"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:background="#00000000"/>
```

For a full tutorial on creating buttons with custom skins and the use of selectors to manage their states, you can check a tutorial I've written some time ago here [(Creating a custom Android button with a resizable skin)](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/).

Answer (score 0):

If your image "111" has no padding itself then simply use android:background"@drawable/111"

Answer (score 0):

Just set this two attributes on the `ImageButton`:

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

With those, you will get the provided src to be stretched, and also if you put some specific `width` and `height` on that `ImageButton` you won't get a rectangle around it.